# SQL function for data retrieval JOIN (second attempt)

Tags: php, mysql, function, fetch

Trying to write an SQL function that collects data from two different tables. It should get the current post id from wp_posts and then find the corresponding images from a table called wp_postdata.

Table 1

```
------------------------------           
id   ||   title   ||  content
------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
---------------------------------------------------------
meta_id   ||   post_id   ||   meta_key   ||   meta_value
---------------------------------------------------------
```

The meta_key that we are after is called _wp_attachment_metadata

My failed attempt ::

```
<?php
$pics = mysql_query("SELECT    id,  
           meta_key_wp_attached_file.meta_value picture 
 FROM      wp_posts
 LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta meta_key_wp_attached_file 
 ON        meta_key_wp_attached_file.post_id = wp_posts.id 
 WHERE     meta_key_wp_attached_file.meta_key = 'picture' 
    ORDER BY picture;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pics)) {
    $thumb = $row['picture'];
    echo '<img src="http://www.golfbrowser.com/wp-content/uploads/'.$thumb.'" />';

}

    ?>
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 0):

Should be: `meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata'`, and you'll need to unserialize the result.

Or you can use the API:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta